# Why is this SQLite Script Affecting Multiple Rows?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, mono, ado.net

I have the following simple SQLite script to create a new database with a versioning table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_versions` (
    `version`   integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `name`  varchar ( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
    `date_defined`  datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `comments`  text
);
INSERT INTO `db_versions` VALUES (0,'initial-create','2017-12-02 14:41:56',NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Running this script in the DB Browser for SQLite logs correctly logs that only 1 row is affected (inserted).  However, when I try to execute this script in code with Mono (Mono.Data.Sqlite), the script apparently affects 2 rows.  Here is that code:

```
using (var conn = new SqliteConnection(_connStr)) {
    await conn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
      using (SqliteCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand()) {
          comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          comm.CommandText = @"
              BEGIN TRANSACTION;
              CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_versions` (
                  `version` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
                  `name`    varchar ( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
                  `date_defined`    datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                  `comments`    text
              );
              INSERT INTO `db_versions` VALUES (0,'initial-create','2017-12-02 14:41:56',NULL);
              COMMIT;
          ";
          int rowsAffected = await comm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
          if (rowsAffected > 1) {
              // Why is this code running??
          }
      }
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting these different results?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get one row returned if you remove the insert and only leave the create?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33  Good question.  Without the `INSERT` statement, the query is not affecting any rows.  I can also confirm that there is only one row in the db after the INSERT statement runs; no second row appears to be added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gah, I figured it out.  The integer `version` field was being defined `AUTOINCREMENT`, which [also adds](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) the largest ROWID to an internal `sqlite_sequence` table.  So there *was* a 2nd row being added.

Comment: I doubt a 2nd row was being added because of autoincrement.

Comment: @CodingYoshi  Well there was: 1 row manually inserted in the new `db_versions` table, and 1 row automatically inserted into the `sqlite_sequence` table by SQLite

Comment: Oh I see. Yes it will do that even on the db browser side. Why would you even care